how to use Waze in Flutter?
I want to show a location with already installed Waze app with my flutter code , i use url_luncher to open it but it doesnt work
this is url :
Uri.parse('the url')

so the print is :
 component name for waze://?q=Sector%201,%20Bucure%C8%99ti,%20Calea%20Rahovei,%20Nr%20276&navigate=yes is null

or using cordinates :
 component name for waze://?ll=37.774929,-122.419416&z=10 is null

none of them work , what is the correct url for using Waze app in the flutter app ?

it should be something like this :
https://waze.com/ul?ll=37.7749,-122.4194&navigate=yes

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
